# how to sort database records stored in array

Tags: php, sorting, standards

i have stored the records from database in a array.
Now i want to sort the array based on the price index and than print the result according.

Can any one help me with this?

Code i tried ..

```
<?php
include('db.php');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");

$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $array[] = $row;
  $price[]=$row['price'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

Output..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => abc
            [email] => abc@gmail.com
            [contact] => 27488887
            [price] => 12AED
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => siddharth
            [email] => dgsfgsjkf@gmail.cm
            [contact] => 7878787
            [price] => 10AED
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => abc
            [email] => def@gmail.com
            [contact] => 4554545
            [price] => 2AED
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => xyz
            [email] => test@gmail.com
            [contact] => 878778
            [price] => 1AED
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => dandas
            [email] => sdskagdsa
            [contact] => 24221
            [price] => 200AED
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => ass
            [email] => asas
            [contact] => 78787
            [price] => 3AED
        )

)
```

Now i want to sort the array obtained as output by price and then display the records..

Comment: You can do this with mysql query : mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY price DESC");

Comment: @vural The value of `price` looks crazy, I don't think normal sort will work.

Comment: i dont want to sort it with mysql order by as i have alphanumeric value for price

Comment: it would be tough to sort price if it contains `AED` in it.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: AED = Arab Emirates Dirham. But I agree: it looks crazy.

Comment: @hherger I know that buddy. `:)`

Comment: no it can be sorted using standard sorting asort...check this:http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Comment: change you mysql query like this  "SELECT * FROM user order by price asc" this is assenting order -descending order like asc to desc

Comment: no tto be done using mysql query